# Rendering a services in a ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs, web, npm, openmrs

I'm trying to rendering an external service in an ReactJS component. I'm working in an OWA for OpenMRS.

This is the React app, this is a component. When I push in some button this should render the next form in the same that component.

[image]

As you can see in the URL, the form is not an HTML page, also an service. In some post I read for render html files, this not the case. How can I work with that in my component?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the docs and found an OpenMRS feature that allows render any OpenMRS page in some panel.

This is the code and pic for I wanted to do

```
...
...
import OpenMRSView from './openmrsView';
...
...
renderForm(url_report) {
    let url = `http://${this.state.server}/` + url_report
    console.log(url);
    this.setState({"url": url});
}

render() {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    if(this.state.seguro=="reportes"){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button id="button_reportes" className="menu_button" style={ styles.button } onClick={() => this.renderForm(JASPER_REG_RAPIDO_ADMISIONES)}>
                Reporte Registro Rapido
                </Button>
                <Button id="button_reportes" className="menu_button" style={ styles.button } onClick={() => this.renderForm(JASPER_ROTULO_ADMISIONES)}>
                Reporte Rotulo
                </Button>
                <Button id="button_reportes" className="menu_button" style={ styles.button } onClick={() => this.renderForm(JASPER_GARANTIA_ADMISIONES)}>
                Reporte Garantia
                </Button>
                <Button id="button_reportes" className="menu_button" style={ styles.button } onClick={() => this.renderForm(JASPER_HOJA_INGRESO_ADMISIONES)}>
                Reporte Hoja de Ingreso
                </Button>
                <Button id="button_reportes" className="menu_button" style={ styles.button } onClick={this.aInicio}>
                Atras
                </Button>
                <Panel bsStyle="info" theme="chemical">
                    <Panel.Body>
                        <OpenMRSView url={this.state.url}/>
                    </Panel.Body>
                </Panel>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

[image]